# Show that there is a $S \in L(V )$ and $v_0 \in V$ such that $T(x) = S(x) + v_0,$ $\forall x \in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let V be an inner product space over the field $F,T : V \rightarrow V$ is a map on V . If $||T(x) - T(y)|| = || x - y||; \forall x; y \in V$.

Show that there is a $S \in L(V)$ and $v_0 \in V$ such that
$T(x) = S(x) + v_0; \forall x; y \in V$

Not sure where to start, would someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is $L(V)$?

Comment: Linear operators space from $V$ to itself.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: Try $v_0 = T(0)$, and showing $S(x) = T(x) - T(0) \in L(V)$.